# E11000 duplicate key error collection when insert doc in mongo

Tags: c#, mongodb

```
 var doc = new BsonDocument();
  documentRepository.AddDocument(doc, "myCollection").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
  
  public async Task<string> AddDocument(BsonDocument item, string collection)
  {
     await _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(collection).InsertOneAsync(item);
     return item["_id"].ToString(); // this is where exception happens
  }
```

> E11000 duplicate key error collection:    myApp.myCollection index:
> *id* dup key: { _id: ObjectId('12381e2b09f14f0001fead43') }       MongoDB.Driver.MongoWriteException: A write operation resulted in an
> error.

```
E11000 duplicate key error collection: myApp.myCollection index: _id_ dup key: { _id: ObjectId('12381e2b09f14f0001fead43') }
    ---> MongoDB.Driver.MongoBulkWriteException`1[MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument]: A bulk write operation resulted in one or more errors.
    
    E11000 duplicate key error collection: myApp.myCollection index: _id_ dup key: { _id: ObjectId('12381e2b09f14f0001fead43') }
    at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.BulkWriteAsync(IClientSessionHandle session, IEnumerable`1 requests, BulkWriteOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.UsingImplicitSessionAsync[TResult](Func`2 funcAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionBase`1.InsertOneAsync(TDocument document, InsertOneOptions options, Func`3 bulkWriteAsync)
```

The confusion comes from the fact that the exception message says that I'm trying to perform bulk insertion

```
MongoDB.Driver.MongoBulkWriteException`1[MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument]
```

whether I'm inserting only one doc as you can see

Comment: Is that the actual ObjectId?

Comment: yes, it is.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This exception happens because you're trying to have the duplicated `_id` value in your collection (you may check this with the mongo shell). The above code itself cannot trigger this error, but this error will happen if you call `AddDocument` twice or more times. Pay attention that after the first AddDocument call, the `item` document will have `_id` value-filled, so in the next attempt of using this object, the driver will attempt to insert the document with the duplicated value

Comment: Actually that makes sense but I'm not seeing how I'm inserting this doc again.

Comment: so, this method `AddDocument` is called only once?

Comment: if so, can you create a small console app and check it there. I don't believe that there is any other way to make this error

Comment: `I'm trying to perform bulk insertion/whether I'm inserting only one doc as you can see` all crud operations are done via bulk internally

Comment: I didn't know that all crud operations are done via bulk internally. Thanks. I'll try with small 
 console app insertion example

Comment: The first 32 bits of an ObjectId are a timestamp - that value has a timestamp from 1979.  Are you using a testing module that might be causing the driver to generate the same values?